# La personne « vaccinée deux doses » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, formulation, santé-et-médecine

> Une personne pleinement vaccinée (deux doses).
> *(Risque par rapport à) une personne **vaccinée deux doses**.*

Je viens de voir ça apparaître dans un [résumé](https://www.lapresse.ca/covid-19/2021-08-26/covid-19/le-quebec-rapporte-603-nouveaux-cas-et-neuf-hospitalisations.php) de la situation au Québec et je l'ai aussi trouvé dans le texte de quelques articles. Ça semble être une précision qui est devenue déterminante dans la phrase de ce genre.

- Comment s'analyse (nature, fonction) *deux doses* dans la deuxième
  phrase ?
- Serait-ce plus usuel précédé d'une préposition et quelle serait-elle
  ?
- Incidemment, pourquoi serait-ce ou non une extension de sens abusive du mot [*dose*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dose) ou comment aurait-on formulé autrement ?

Comment: Je pense qu'on n'a a pas fini de créer des expressions. En rentrant chez moi tout à l'heure je me suis prise à dire : « et bien voilà je triple dosé (tripledosé) ! »

Comment: Tridosée, tridosaire ? Je me souviens primovacciné... tertiovacciné ? Ouais. @None

Comment: ah oui tertiovacciné, j'aurais dû penser ça. Et ça me donne droit à un certificat de « parcours vaccinal terminé ».

Answer (score 1):

Ça s'analyse comme « breveté SGDG », qui est un terme bien établi  ([réf.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sgdg%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)), ou encore et plus exactement comme « fait-main » [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fait-main).

> **fait-main** Composé de *fait* et de *main*.  Adjectif
> fait-main \fɛ.mɛ̃\ masculin et féminin identiques
>
> Fabriqué manuellement ou de façon artisanale et non-industrialisée.

**1/** La nature du terme est évidemment adjectivale et sa fonction est celle d'épithète.

**2/** Ce qui vient à l'esprit dans le cas de « fait-main », c'est la préposition « à ».  Ce n'est pas une préposition qui semble naturelle pour « vaccinée deux doses » et elle est très loin d'exprimer ce qui  est impliqué ;  la formation telle qu'analysée selon le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/main) repose sur le principe de l'ellipse, et on peut supposer un bon nombre de possibilités de combinaisons à omettre par ellipse.

> P. ell. Cousu, fait main; broderie main. Poudrier guilloché main (Catal. jouets [Trois Quartiers], 1936).Pour la bicyclette et le sport, vous aimerez ces gants en tricot main pour le dessus, et à l'intérieur, de peau de chèvre, cousu sellier (L'Œuvre, 31 mars 1941).

La préposition « de » est néanmoins à peu près convenable, même si elle ne peut pas remplacer  plusieurs mots.

- personne vaccinée de deux doses.

**3/** Il n'y a aucune extension abusive du mot « dose », pas plus qu'il y en aurait une du mot « main » dans « fait main ». Il s'agit seulement d'une formation sur un modèle donné qui ne prend de sens que par définition, c'est un nouveau mot. Un formulation en terme d'une expression pourrait être comme suit.

- vaccinée une seconde  fois après un laps de temps nécessaire pour laisser l'organisme assimiler la première dose

---

*Détail suggéré par un  commentaire de user Xoudo*

Qu'il ne manque rien entre « breveté » et « SGDG » et/ou après « SGDG » ne peut pas être soutenu bien longtemps si on se demande ce que signifie vraiment ce terme. Il a le sens suivant : «  breveté **avec la réserve que l'invention est** sans garantie du gouverment **en cas de vice de conception ou d'erreur de description** » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans_garantie_du_gouvernement)).  On peut très bien faire dire autre chose à ce terme pour lequel est exigée une définition de dictionnaire : «  breveté **avec la réserve que l'invention est** sans garantie du gouverment **si non construite par un fabricant agréé par le gouvernement** » ; ce n'est plus la même chose. Le terme est donc bien fondé sur une ellipse que seule une définition peut préciser.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Ça me semblait clair, mais je vois que j'aurais peut-être dû prendre plus de soin dans cette explication. Non, « dose » n'est pas l'adjectif ; parallèlement à « fait(-)main », que le Wiktionnaire reconnait en tant qu'adjectif, c'est « vaccinée deux dose » qui est la formation nouvelle, que l'on définit. On pourrait même écrire cela « vaccinée-deux-doses ». L'assemblage « vaccinée deux dose », lui ne peut pas être analysé grammaticalement quant à ses constituents puisqu'on le définit comme étant une nouvelle unité lexicale, c'est à dire, en d'autres termes, comme un mot. (1/2)

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Il devrait être évident que, à partir de la définition — et il faudra une définition, comme pour « fait-main »—, la partie « deux doses » n'apparait pas en tant que terme ayant une fonction grammaticale qui soit bien claire. La définition peut même ne pas contenir « deux doses ».  On aborde là la question des expressions figées, non analysables. (2/2)

Comment: L'association me semble plus usuelle entre _vaccinée deux doses_ et _vaccinée deux fois_ qu'entre la première et _fait-main_ qui demande comme je viens de l'expliquer un contexte syntaxique ou grammatical différent il me semble. Mais oui l'ellipse et la réduction, mais finalement je la vois uniquement orthographique (l'absence de parenthèse essentiellement). Mais ça c'est ma perception.

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Il n'y a rien de plus usuel ou de moins usuel: on fait dire à « deux doses » tout aussi bien « une double dose en une seule fois ». Tout n'est question que de _définition_. On veut une définition particulière ou on ne la veut pas. Ce qu'on veut ici, c'est « deux fois » (pour commencer) et c'est la base de la définition que j'avance, et qui est très probablement très proche de ce que la réalité demande.

Comment: Bien oui et non, je veux dire ce serait une lexicalision très rapide pour ainsi dire instantanée, d'où mon encore plus grande hésitation à voir ça comme une locution à toute fin pratique. En fait je pense que c'est justement parce qu'on a de la difficulté à formuler la phrase complète avec le participe passé _vacciné_ plutôt qu'avec le verbe _recevoir_ et _deux doses_ qu'on opte pour ce procédé alors qu'avec _fois_ on n'aurait pas cette difficulté. Je ne trouve pas ça très porteur de sens. Si on employait _vacciné deux doses_ pour dire _avec le même vaccin_ ce serait p-ê. différent. Entk merci

Comment: Pas d'accord pour *breveté SGDG* qui est l'abbréviation d'une phrase très classique (brevété sans garantie du gouvernement), contrairement à *vacciné deux doses*, ou il y a clairement quelque chose qui manque.

Comment: @XouDo Malheureusement, je ne vois votre commentaire que maintenant, alors que je vérifie ma réponse après un nouveau vote. J'ajoute dans le texte une précision ; en cas de doute ou d'erreur de ma part, me le signaler si ça vous intéresse.